# InterlockedCompareExchange128 Usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

I am trying to use the MS VC++ Intrinsic InterlockedCompareExchange128 function.

As a hello-world, I am trying to compare a 16byte address with itself, and replace it with something else. This compiles, but it's not working - the address is not exchanged with new values. The const_cast is used to make it compile (otherwise it cries for not being able to cast volatile).

```
typedef struct t_node
{
    volatile __int64 arr[2];
}node;

int main()
{   

    node *a = new node();

    a->arr[0] = 100;
    a->arr[1] = 1;

    __int64 i = 200;
    __int64 j = 500;

    char r = _InterlockedCompareExchange128(a->arr, i,j, const_cast<__int64*>(&a->arr[0]));

    cout<<endl<<"Interlocked Compare Res: "<<r;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514094.aspx):

```
unsigned char _InterlockedCompareExchange128(
   __int64 volatile * Destination,
   __int64 ExchangeHigh,
   __int64 ExchangeLow,
   __int64 * ComparandResult
);
```

> [in, out] ComparandResult
>   Pointer to an array of two 64-bit integers (considered as a 128-bit field) to compare with the destination. **On output, this is overwritten with the original value of the destination**.

Thus, what happens is in pseudocode:

```
if(ComparandResult != Destination)
{
    temp = Destination
    Destination = ExchangeHigh:ExchangeLow
    ComparandResult = temp
}
```

What happens when `Destination == ComparandResult` (your case) is:

```
if(ComparandResult != Destination)
{
    temp = Destination
    Destination = ExchangeHigh:ExchangeLow
    Destination = temp
}
```

Which is a nop.
In addition there is a note for that in the same page:

> Note
>   The value of ComparandResult is always overwritten. After the
>   lock instruction, this intrinsic immediately copies the initial value
>   of Destination to ComparandResult. For this reason, ComparandResult
>   and Destination should point to separate memory locations to avoid
>   unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for making me go back to the documentation!